# How to enter GPA numbers instead?

Tags: java, calculator

I want to change the input to ensure that integers, not letters, are inputted by the user, and that the program understands the numbers out into the machine (which would understand the number and recognize that number as a certain GPA grade). I only understand how to put in letters and plus/minus signs (which are recognized by the enumerators as certain grade numbers), but I want to reverse this procedure and have numbers put in (and be recognized as grade letters). Is there a way to do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
        //imports scanner
        public class Part1 {
            enum LetterGrades {
              A_PLUS ("A+", 4.33),
              A      ("A" , 4   ),
              A_MINUS("A-", 3.67),
              B_PLUS ("B+", 3.33),
              B      ("B" , 3   ),
              B_MINUS("B-", 2.67),
              C_PLUS ("C+", 2.33),
              C      ("C" , 2   ),
              C_MINUS("C-", 1.67),
              D      ("D" , 1   ),
              F      ("F" , 0   ),
              FX     ("FX", 0   );



              private final String grade_;
              private final double value_;

              //CONSTRUCTOR
              private LetterGrades(String grade, double value) {
                  grade_ = grade;
                  value_ = value;
              }

              public static double getValueFromGrade(String grade) {
                  for (LetterGrades letterGrade : LetterGrades.values()) {
                      if (letterGrade.grade_.equals(grade)) {
                          return letterGrade.value_;
                      }
                  }
                  System.out.println("Invalid grade");
                  return 0.0;
              }
            }






          public static void main (String args[]){

              String grade = "";

              double credit1;
              double credit2;
              double credit3;
              double credit4;
              double gradeValue=0;
             //Creates 4 credits
              double totPtsClass1=0;
              double totPtsClass2=0;
              double totPtsClass3=0;
              double totPtsClass4=0;
              double totPts=0;
              double totalCredits= 0;
              double gpa;
              //Points in classes, GPA
              System.out.println("Welcome to the UNG GPA Calculator!");
              String message;

              Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
              System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
              message = scan.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
              message = scan.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Enter your major: ");
              message = scan.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Enter the class number of your first class: ");
              message = scan.nextLine();

              Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);


              System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits of the class 1 (A number)");
              credit1 = console.nextDouble();
              System.out.println("Now you will enter the grade from the chart: A = 4.00, A- = 3.67, B+ = 3.33, B = 3.00, B- = 2.67, C+ = 2.33, C = 2.00, C- = 1.67, D+ = 1.33, D = 1.00, F = 0.00. Please enter your grades for the class 1(Capital letters such as A,B+, C-)");
              grade = console.next();


              gradeValue = LetterGrades.getValueFromGrade(grade);
              totPtsClass1 = gradeValue * credit1;

              System.out.println("Enter the class number of your second class: ");
              message = scan.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits of the class 2 (A number)");
              credit2 = console.nextDouble();
              System.out.println("Please enter your grades for the class 2 (Capital letters such as A,B+, C-)");
              grade = console.next();


              gradeValue = LetterGrades.getValueFromGrade(grade);
              totPtsClass2 = gradeValue * credit1;


              System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits of the class 3 (A number)");
              credit3 = console.nextDouble();
              System.out.println("Please enter your grades for the class 3 (Capital letters such as A,B+, C-)");
              grade = console.next();


              gradeValue = LetterGrades.getValueFromGrade(grade);
              totPtsClass3 = gradeValue * credit1;


              System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits of the class 4 (A number)");
              credit4 = console.nextDouble();
              System.out.println("Please enter your grades for the class 4 (Capital letters such as A,B+, C-)");
              grade = console.next();

              gradeValue = LetterGrades.getValueFromGrade(grade);
              totPtsClass4 = gradeValue * credit1;


              totPts= totPtsClass1 + totPtsClass2 + totPtsClass3 + totPtsClass4;
              totalCredits = credit1 + credit2 + credit3 + credit4;
              gpa= totPts / totalCredits;

              System.out.printf("Your GPA is: %.2f\n", + gpa);
         }
    }
```

I need to make sure the user can enter the floating point number from the list of enumerators (decimals entered corresponding to certain GPA's) How do I assign the user input to a String variable (the program reading it in and assign it to a properly named variable)?

Comment: 1. Search each of the `enum`s for its value, compare with the number you have.  2. Use a hashing function to look up the relevant enum directly from the number grade.

Comment: I see you basically have #1 in `getValueFromGrade`, just do the same thing but search the values, not the letters.

Comment: I have tried this on Drjava, but it demands to be recompiled. Do you mind showing a segment of how this is done?

Comment: You might want to look into using `BigDecimal` instead of `double` - it makes it easier to make an exact match on the numeric value. Also, try to make a smaller example when posting a question here (you could have removed the code around asking for names, class numbers, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to your `LetterGrades` enum:

```
public static LetterGrades fromValue(double value) {
    Optional<LetterGrades> result =
            Arrays.stream(LetterGrades.values())
                    .filter(grade -> Math.abs(grade.value_ - value) < 0.01)
                    .findFirst();

    if (!result.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid grade value");
    }

    return result.orElse(FX);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible Solution:

- Any grade above 4.33: A+ (4.33)
- 4.32 to 4.0: A (4.0)
- 3.99 to 3.67: A- (3.67)
- ...
- 0.99 to 0: F (0)
- any negative: NULL

---

**LetterGrade.java**

```
public enum LetterGrade {

    A_PLUS ("A+", 4.33),
    A      ("A" , 4   ),
    A_MINUS("A-", 3.67),
    B_PLUS ("B+", 3.33),
    B      ("B" , 3   ),
    B_MINUS("B-", 2.67),
    C_PLUS ("C+", 2.33),
    C      ("C" , 2   ),
    C_MINUS("C-", 1.67),
    D      ("D" , 1   ),
    F      ("F" , 0   ),
    FX     ("FX", 0   );

    private final String grade;

    private final double value;

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private LetterGrade(String grade, double value) {
        this.grade = grade;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static LetterGrade getLetterGrade(String grade) {
        for (LetterGrade letterGrade : LetterGrade.values()) {
            if (letterGrade.grade.equals(grade)) {
                return letterGrade;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static LetterGrade getLetterGrade(double value) {
        for (LetterGrade letterGrade : LetterGrade.values()) {
            if (letterGrade.value <= value) {
                return letterGrade;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Drjava ran the program, but it's output was Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]. Do i need to add the method accepting String?

Comment: This class describes the enum LetterGrade, nothing else. Add your main method, adjust the names since some refactoring is done. In my opinion it's way better to call getLetterGrade(String).getValue() rather than getValueFromGrade(String).

Comment: I subsituted getLetterGrade for getValueFromGrade, though I am still unable to enter the numbers, as the program accepts letters